# I want to change label with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I need some help. I am new to javascript and want to change "label for font_color" and "label for font_family" with onclick. Right now, the text that I enter in the input change, but not in the label that I want the changes.

```
function swap_color_and_font() {
    document.getElementsById("font_color").style.color="pink"; 
    document.getElementById("font_family").style.fontFamily="arial"; 
}

<form>  
     <fieldset>  
     <label for="font_color">Font color</label><br/>
     <input type="text" id="font_color" value=""/><br/>
     <label for="font_family">Font</label><br/>
     <input type="text" id="font_family" value=""/><br/>
     <input onclick="swap_color_and_font()" value="Byt ut färg och font" type="button"/>
     </fieldset>
```

Comment: Typo.  There is no `document.getElementsById` function.  As an aside, you should always check your browser console for errors, it's telling you about this one.

Comment: Do you want to change the color and fon family of the label element or input element with mentioned ID?

Comment: I want to change the color and font family of the label element

Answer (score 0):

because the id="" is in  the input so when the function gets running it will affect the input not the label so you can put the 2 id in the labels

Answer (score 0):

You can add ids to the label and change their styles instead

```
function swap_color_and_font() {
    document.getElementById("label_1").style.color="pink"; 
    document.getElementById("label_2").style.fontFamily="arial"; 
}
<fieldset>  
 <label for="font_color" id="label_1">Font color</label><br/>
 <input type="text" id="font_color" value=""/><br/>
 <label for="font_family" id="label_2">Font</label><br/>
 <input type="text" id="font_family" value=""/><br/>
 <input onclick="swap_color_and_font()" value="Byt ut färg och font" 
 type="button"/>
</fieldset>
```